# What characteristics make a graph look professional?

Tags: data-visualisation, chart-design

I'm documenting a technical/scientific project, in which I'm needing an extensive amount of graphs to represent the data.

I would like this graphs to be as clear and representative as possible. Of course the priority is using properly the data and choose the most appropriate medium (meaning for instance bar plot against scatter plot).

But from a design perspective, what elements are important to make sure that the graphs are high quality and look professional?

I'm aware of the fact that they should be preferrably (if not mandatorily) vector images rather than rasters, and that the markings shouldn't be such to hide details of the represented data. But other than that?

Comment: Go read these books: http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_vdqi

Comment: I'll wait to see what others think but as it stands this question is pretty broad. Professional is very subjective to audience and culture. As @DA01 just beat me to it though, look at Edward Tufte's theories and rules.

Comment: I might get stuck in and try to give you an answer later, but here is  [what not to do.](http://www.visualsquirrels.net/2014/06/09/charts-the-horror-of-three-dimensions/)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake tagging with information graphics. The scope is technical/scientific documentation, like papers or reports.

Comment: Technically a chart *is* an information graphic. It's just that the term 'information graphic' has been abused and is now a synonym for google click-bait. :)

Comment: This may not be the best place to ask. Since graphics designers dont do scientific stuff mostly, as most scientists are too cash strapped to hire one.

Answer (score 2):

**For bar charts:**

- If there are data labels above the bars or at the end of the bars,
  center them and make sure they are all the same distance from the end
  of the bar.
- Your axes should be named. Center the label.
- Use a key if you have more than one set of data. Center the key
  dingbat on the key label. (That is, the little green square should be centered vertically on the first letter of the key label.)
- If you have a series of bar charts comparing the same things, make
  sure your key colors are consistent from chart to chart.
- Your axis labels should be legible. Don't put them at 45
  degrees. Make them smaller if they need to fit, or go every other
  item if necessary.
- Use $ or % on every tick mark of an axis, not just the first one.

**For line charts:**

- Most of the same rules as bar charts. If you have labels above the
  data points, make them all the same distance from the point dingbat.
- If you have two lines and two sets of labels, color-key the labels if
  possible. (It's easier to follow a red set of numbers and a blue set
  than to pick out two sets of black.)

**For pie charts:**

- Put the label in the center of each pie slice. If it doesn't fit, put
  it outside with a line. The "whisker" connecting the label to the
  slice can go at an angle, but then should become an underline under
  the label.
- Try to make all the outside labels align to left and right rather
  than floating randomly.

Comment: and PLEASE PLEASE avoid using 3d for pie charts and bargraphs, unless it's REALLY a life or death choice.

Comment: @tomtomtom I don't mind some subtle 3D, but not at the cost of legibility.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OMmdq.png here for example (image posted below) the 3d is totally pointless and in the pie chart on the bottom right corner it even alters the perception of which slice is the biggest. There are really really few cases where 3d is justified, and where other options are totally fine anyways in my opinion

Answer (score -1):

I think the number one thing that will make the graphs look professional is how consistent they are with the other material they are presented with. Here's some things to look at:

1. Colors - Make sure the colors are in keeping with the rest of the project
2. Type - Use the same font as the rest of the project
3. Spacing - Keep the same margins and distances between graphs as you use between paragraphs

Those are some thoughts to keep in mind when placing and designing them.

The actual theme or whatever you want to call it is pretty subjective... The common trend right now is **flat** (look at the design of this site). Here's a few info graphic templates that are around just do a google image search for infographic and pick a style that fits with the style you've got for your project.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Some of these are just bad. Particularly those last 2. Though I'm also perplexed at "Infographic Pie Chart" on the first group, which appears to be a venn diagram.

Comment: I have no idea what the point of that last one is. "How to hide meaningful data in bells and whistles?"

Comment: I can see the point on the last one (its off now, I was wanting to show that there are MANY ways to design charts).